# So There is no simple group of order $2187$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a group of order $2187=3^7$. I used Sylow's theorem and got Sylow 3-subgroup as my group. How do I continue?

Comment: The center of a $p$-group is non trivial.

Comment: is there a proof without centres, if possible

Comment: What do you have against centers?